# API path failed to match after migrate from javax to jakarta

Tags: java, jax-rs, quarkus, jakarta-migration

I am upgrading quarkus from 1.x to 3.6, which requires migrating from `javax` to `jakarta`.

Part of the APIs unittest start to give 404 error after changing `javax` to `jakarta`.
For those failures, I found requests haven't even reached the controller function, indicating the API path failed to match.

The APIs are defined like this:

```
@Path("/api/topology-graph")
public class Resource {
    @POST
    @Path("/v1/maps/{map-id}/omap-stats")
    public Response addStats(@PathParam("map-id") Long mapId) { 
        ...
    }

     @GET
     @Path("/v1/maps/{map-id}/omap-stats/edges/{edge-id}/age")
     public Response getAge(
         @PathParam("map-id") Long mapId,
         @PathParam("edge-id") Long edgeId) {
         ...
     }

}
```

Quarkus log:

```
2023-12-25 21:17:20,161 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) requestRouted null HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/api/topology-graph/v1/maps/1/omap-stats, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@5d258289]
2023-12-25 21:17:20,165 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) requestRouted null HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/api/topology-graph/v1/maps/1/omap-stats, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@5d258289]
2023-12-25 21:17:20,166 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) requestRouted null HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/api/topology-graph/v1/maps/1/omap-stats, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@5d258289]
2023-12-25 21:17:20,166 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) requestRouted null HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/api/topology-graph/v1/maps/1/omap-stats, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@5d258289]
2023-12-25 21:17:20,166 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) requestRouted / HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/api/topology-graph/v1/maps/1/omap-stats, currentRoutePath=null, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@5d258289]
2023-12-25 21:17:20,166 DEBUG [WebApplicationException] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Restarting handler chain for exception exception: jakarta.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.handle(RestInitialHandler.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:121)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:23)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:10)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1286)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:144)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:59)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:37)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1286)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:144)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:339)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:332)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1286)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:144)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter.handle(CORSFilter.java:199)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.cors.CORSFilter.handle(CORSFilter.java:21)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1286)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:144)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$4.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:192)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$4.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:181)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

2023-12-25 21:17:20,167 DEBUG [io.qua.mic.run.bin.ver.VertxHttpServerMetrics] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) responseEnd io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerResponse@5e5431c7, HttpRequestMetric [initialPath=/api/topology-graph/v1/maps/1/omap-stats, currentRoutePath=/, templatePath=null, request=io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequest@5d258289]
```

I did more experiment by changing `/v1/maps/` to `/v2/maps/`, then the path can be matched ... this behavior does not make much sense to me.

Any one has met with similar issue?

Comment: Have you tried using our tooling? See https://quarkus.io/blog/quarkus-3-upgrade/

Comment: do you have any configurations related to http settings in your application.properties which you didn't migrate ?

Comment: Thanks for the info @geoand

But our current quarkus version is too old and not provide the `update` support.

In addition, our gradle project has several quakrus micro service that depends on a shared submodule. All of them depends on quarkus. I wonder how the `update` can work in such case.

Comment: What imports are you using?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

import java.util.Set;


import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Context;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import jakarta.ws.rs.*;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

Comment: The problem seems to be I have one class with multiple router methods, some of them annotated with /v1 and others with /v2. After I separate the /v2 methods into its own class, the API paths can be correctly matched.

this problem did not have when I was using quarkus 1.36

Comment: Another question I forgot to ask : does it fail only on unit test or also in running app ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens
both unittest and the regular server.

Comment: This is quite strange. I found [this example](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/vertx-quickstart/src/main/java/org/acme) in quarkus quickstarts. Maybe it some changes in the dependencies or even a bug in quarkus itself

Answer (score 0):

The resource looks OK and works in a new Quarkus 3.2 project.
You may have some configuration or dependency that is breaking the path.

Check that you don't have an HTTP base URL defined in your application.properties.

Open http://localhost:8080/q/dev-ui/ and http://localhost:8080/q/dev-ui/io.quarkus.quarkus-resteasy-reactive/endpoint-scores where you can see the registered endpoints for your application.

[image]

One way to find what is causing the issue is to comment/disable parts of the code until you find what is breaking it or move the code to a new project.